# WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0 wso2:vault-lookup() returning alias name and not encrypted password

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I did add the secret to my `deployment.toml` and then encrypt it using the cipher-tool.sh:

```
[secrets]
orga_client_key = "NuwQtop76Oq6OAWGpkhywAeLkRj1nPiAFlBMzmni2FZO/APTp5EyKl6Hc+xlb5pBUdo3C/cd32eyzGHf/LjtCaSg8CaspYa35au0H19pP5h/9pymnqiKvdXFocbDuNLoFvKp4lMGbh9rd8DmMn6kzerTmAFb1PsvxjCSB$=="
```

My problem is that then when i try to acces this secret from synapse mediation i only get the alias name itself.

*synapse log mediator:*

```
<log level="custom">
   <property expression="wso2:vault-lookup('orga_client_key')" name="TEST KEY"/>
</log>
```

*console log:*

```
INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - TEST KEY = orga_client_key
```

Which is the string I am passing.

I found these two that reference the same problem but I'm struggling understanding is there' s a solution to it.

https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/issues/2050
https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-ei/issues/1085

Thanks

Tried encrypting password with WSO2 MI and the cipher-tool. Want the password to be accesible in the mediation flow but function only returns string.

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you sure the value you encrypted in not `orga_client_key`.

Comment: yes, I am. Tbh by `wso2:vault-lookup('some_string')` I get printed `some_string`.

Comment: Download a fresh MI distribution and then list the exact steps you follow. I'll see whether I can reproduce it in that way.

Comment: I did: downloaded wso2mi-4-2-0 added

`[secrets]
orga_client_key = "[some_value]"`

Ran the command:

`./chiper-tool.sh -Dconfigure`

Restarted the integrator and then tried logging the secret as in my original post

Comment: I would also add that, strangely (?), after restarting the server I do not get prompted for password at server startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. Basically the encryption was done correctly but starting the server (in a linux env) with:

```
sh ./micro-integrator.sh start
```

I also needed to place the keystore password in a `password-persist` file in the micro integrator home.